# Dimmer Switch in 3 Gang Box

Tags: dimmer-switch

Quick question from a beginner. Trying to install 2 dimmer switches in this 3 gang box. In the picture, you'll see that I connected the positive and neutral already to the first dimmer switch. The third switch on the right is the one that I am not changing. There was just one long piece of ground wire here used that went to all 3 switches. Is the best way to connect the ground from the dimmer switches (stranded wire) to the ground wire that is there by using those green wire nuts? And then just wrap it regularly around the last switch? Any other tips? All help is appreciated, thank you[image]

Comment: The correct wording for the wires to the switch is hot and switched hot.  Simple switches do not use/have neutral.  For the ground might want to pigtail shorter ground wires to the switches from the main ground.

Comment: Read the instructions that came with the dimmers, but you might find that you have to bend off one row of aluminum tabs if you want the dimmers to fit side by side. This de-rates the dimmer a bit, but usually not a problem with led fixtures. (You might also find that you don’t have to break the tabs if you put the conventional switch in the middle.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the green thread-through wire nuts to attach the dimmer grounds to the ground wire attached to the switch.  Wrap the switch terminals with electrical tape. Be careful when you fold the wires back in, especially to keep the bare copper away from the switch terminals (even with the tape - it can get scraped off).

Answer (score 1):

If you have some extra 12 ga wire and wire nuts, it would be easier to trim the extra long wire and attach that wire along with all 3 switch grounds using an extra wire nut.  That means fitting 4 wires into an empty 2nd wire nut instead of 6 wires into the original weird greenie with the twisted up business.

If you feel obligated to re-use the greenie with 6 or 7 wires inside, take some time to make all the ends straight and triple check that you've got each wire snugly and permanently attached after twisting.  Those greenies are not designed for 7 wires, and trying to cram them in there gracefully is a chore and a half.

I would not use any electrical tape here, and if I found someone else using it I would be mildly alarmed that something might be wrong.